# Crosser browser DHTML widget for edittinig large blocks of text

Tags: jquery, editor, webbrowser-control, dhtml

Can someone recommend a cross brower widget and/or technique that would allow users to work with large blocks of text in a browser? By work with text, I mean edit, search, and replace text. Ideally we're looking for something like a jquery-like DHTML component - not a Flash or RIA component (which may not run or not be allowed to run in all our customer environments).

Background: Our ERP software generates a large (200-500K) text configuration file that we would like to allow admins to tweak online in a text edit/text area type widget without having to save the file locally, edit in notepad, and then upload back to our site. Because these files are large, admins need the ability to search on specific keywords in order to make edits. We don't have the ability to break these large configuration files into smaller chunks because users need to see the full file for context, sequence, and user comments.

Suggestions appreciated!

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

We've used this To some effect:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/FCKEditor/

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Mootools:

http://siteroller.net/projects/moorte/

read about it here:
http://mootools.net/blog/